# How to create multiple typescript/angularjs 1 project and references them with module is AMD

Tags: angularjs, typescript, gulp, requirejs, amd

i have large project angular js 1 with typescript, and i use external module for this projects and my projects has core like a library and app, it will reference core lib and call service from core.

my structure i design is

```
index.html
----------- app
---------------- my-core
---------------- my-app
----------- assets
--------------libs
```

i use

1. gulp for javascript task manager
2. requirejs for loader module

each folder i create an index.ts file to re-export module in folder

my tsconfig for core:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "amd",
      "target": "es6",
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "outFile": "../my-core/app/references/myCore.js",
      "rootDir": "../my-core",
      "declaration": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "inlineSourceMap": true,
      "inlineSources": true
  }
}
```

my tsconfig for my-app

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "amd",
      "target": "es6",
      "rootDir": "",
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "lib": ["dom", "es2015.promise", "es6"]
  }
}
```

Can suggestion me for my structure. how to reference with core, and build, deploy??..

Thanks